# React-admin: update List on listener event

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-admin

I am trying to use **react-admin**. I am not an expert on React.
I want to keep a list of items updated with the firestore (firebase) database in **realtime** (using the onSnapshot listener by firestore)

Up to now, I am able to use react-admin to show a list of items from firestore (firebase) database and showing them on a list, but I don't know where to put the listener and how to keep the list **updated in realtime**.

What I have up to now is a dataProvider for react-admin like this:

```
const dataProvider = {
getList: async (resourceName, params) => {
  console.log(params);
  if (params.pagination) {
    let values = [];

    //Firestore Query
    let snapshots = await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("items")
      .get();
    for (const snapshot of snapshots.docs) {
      const data = snapshot.data();
      values.push(data);
    }
    //End Firestore query

  if (params.filter) {
      values = values.filter((item) => {
        let meetsFilters = true;
        for (const key of Object.keys(params.filter)) {
          meetsFilters = item[key] === params.filter[key];
        }
        return meetsFilters;
      });
    }

    if (params.sort) {
      values.sort(
        sortBy(
          `${params.sort.order === "ASC" ? "" : "-"}${params.sort.field}`
        )
      );
    }

    const keys = values.map((i) => i.id);
    const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
    const _start = (page - 1) * perPage;
    const _end = page * perPage;
    const data = values ? values.slice(_start, _end) : [];
    const ids = keys.slice(_start, _end) || [];
    const total = values ? values.length : 0;
    console.log({ data, ids, total });

    return { data, ids, total };
}
```

}

I want to insert a listener "onSnapshot" by Firebase replacing the Firestore Query in my code. 
The listener onSnapshot is fired every time a new document is added in the firestore collection. It should be like this (according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

```
firebase.firestore().collection("items")
.onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
    var cities = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        //Do Something
    });
});
```

How could I insert this listener in place of the Firestore Query in my code?
The problem is that if I put it directly in place of the Firestore Query, the getList method never reaches the return statement.

Comment: Please add the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem so we can help fix the problem.

Comment: @Rmaxx, I added some code to better explain my problem. Is it clearer now?

Comment: yes, very much , i upped the question..

Comment: Have you tried React-admin -firebase , they have the option for  realtime db. But the data provider will not trigger the updates on the List UI. Is there a way for React-admin to detect the changes in the databse and update the UI list with the latest entries on the database?